# The right join of postgres return unexpected result

Tags: postgresql

I have the following query

```
select date, count(t.p_id)
                   from someTable t
                   right join generate_series('2019-09-01'::timestamp, least(current_date, '2019-09-05'), interval '1 day') AS g(date) on t.someDate @> date
                   where t.s_id = 42 and t.skl_id = 5
                   group by date
                   order by date
```

In case if there is nothing for t.s_id or t.skl_id I get back empty result.
But as far as I have right join for `generate_series...` I expect to get 5 raws.
What I missed?

Comment: For sql related questions please include a minimal data sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a condition in the `WHERE` clause, it is (logically) evaluated *after* the join is performed. So such a `WHERE` clause can remove all the rows from the join.

If you rather want `NULL` values on the left side, you have to remove the `WHERE` clause and move them to the `ON` clause.

Comment: Uh, I thought where clause can't influence on that. Thanks!

Comment: Or alternatively use a nested query, which might be more declarative.